# Cannot read property of undefined, How to avoid the crash?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have the following code below

```
<Link to={`/single/${post.id}`}>
```

When I delete the post, the post becomes undefined. and I get a crash

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

How can I gracefully Deal with this and avoid crashes. I want it so that if post is undefined it returns an error page or something. But I don't know how to write it.

Comment: [use conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)  `{post && <Link to={\`/single/${post.id}\`}>}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and do something like this:

```
 <Link to={ post ? `/single/${post.id}` : null }>
```

This says that if there is a post link to the `post.id`, else it's `null`.

Your other option is to only render the link if there is a `post`.

```
{post && <Link to={`/single/${post.id}`}>}
```

Comment: thank you, I'll mark as right answer when it lets me